# How to configure static variables shared between different applications under one App pool?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a set of applications under one app pool on my Server, some of them shares the same resources that should be exclusively owned, as a result, I want to use a static dictionary that could be shared between these applications to hold the owners of token in a shared dll library and let each application apply for the token through the library:

```
    public class SessionCache
{
    private static SessionCache _sessionData = new SessionCache();
    public static SessionCache Instance { get { return _sessionData; } }

    private Dictionary<string, SessionCacheItem> _dataDic = new Dictionary<string, SessionCacheItem>();
 ...}
```

Unfortunately, the static SessionCache.Instance is not shared between different applications through the default settings, is there a way to config multiple applications share the same static variable? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Nothing remotely reasonable comes to mind.  :-)

If this is really your requirement, you could use a SQL database server (lots of options to choose from), or use one of the newish "NoSQL" servers like [Redis (REmote DIctionary Server)](http://redis.io/), which StackOverflow.com itself uses for caching (just Google it up), or something like [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/)

Or, you could do something like create a WCF service, although that seems as if it might be a lot of work for what you want to accomplish.  System.Type instances are shared across all apps within an AppDomain.  But there are just oodles of reasons why you would not want to share a static variable between multiple apps even if you could.